# Extract/print every 3rd occurence of pattern

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I need to extract/print lines until a stop pattern. This needs to happen after every 3rd occurrence of start pattern, i.e `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` and continue until the end of the file. Below is an example of the log file.

```
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3
Stop_pattern
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7
Stop_pattern
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
some text
ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
Stop_pattern
```

Desired output:

```
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3
//separate if possible
Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7
//separate if possible
Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
//separate if possible
```

Comment: Question exists with answers at http://stackoverflow.com/q/26144033/7552

Comment: that print particular number of line. this quetion is having stop_pattern

Comment: Could you show us your desired output? Do you want everything from the 3rd `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` to the end?

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk '/Stop_pattern/{c=0; print ""}; c>=3;/ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND/{c++} ' file 
Extract line 1
Extract line 2
Extract line 3

Extract line 5
Extract line 6
Extract line 7

Extract line 9
Extract line 10
Extract line 11
```

Comment: not everything from third occurrence, there's stop pattern where it should stop printing and start looking for 3rd occurrence from then on till it finds next stop pattern,

Comment: @user4099249 OK, that's why I asked you to show your desired output. Please [edit] your question and add it (don't post it in a comment). Anyway, I updated my answer, it should do what you want now.

Comment: Sorry I'm new forum so did not not there's way to edit question.I see two answer of yours which one I should try, I need start patter and stop patter to be printed as well.

Comment: @user4099249 could you please, _please_ hit the [edit] link under your question ( or this one: [edit]) and show us your desired output? You keep adding these details. The new version prints both start and end patterns. Now, please [edit] your question and add your desired output.

Comment: is it readable?

Comment: @user4099249 it's perfect, thanks. I have updated my answer, it should do what you want.